# How to edit element.style { } in wordpress so that it applies to my gridbuilder widget

Tags: css, wordpress, styles

I want to modify so that the text in my box is displayed in white and not in black.

```
[Screenshot][1]





It works in the google console so I'm sure it's this attribute that needs to be changed.
I tried to modify the CSS code in the wordpress editor as well as in the gridbuilder editor, but nothing works...


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfuPY.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"element.style{}" isn't an element inside your code. You need to find the correct element in your code and apply it to that specific element.

See this link [Chrome Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/)

Comment: Ah ok ! Thanks to you I find the correct element :D Thanks a lot !!!